# Cypress: I want run tests in 100 spec files by login one time and persist login for every file. Is it possible?

Tags: authentication, local-storage, cypress, persist

I have almost 100 specs files including multiple tests. I want run all these specs files by login one time.
I dont want my cypress should login process every time on every spec file
It it possible to persist single login for all spec files

Comment: try and use: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/session in 2022

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at our "Logging in" recipes https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes#logging-in-recipes - most of them log in once using `before` hook, and then save the cookie / token in a local variable and set it again and again in `beforeEach` hook

Comment: this is solution for multiple tests in single file but I want login persist for multiple spec files

Comment: ok, when you do `cypress run` Cypress will start the browser for each spec - destroying anything from the previous spec. So you don't have many choices - maybe saving login information as a file on disk via `cy.writeFile` or `cy.task` might help - still I think this could be unnecessary complexity just to avoid a login per spec file

Comment: then what is the solution. so you want to me to write multiple test in single file
in my opinion that is not good approach what do you think?

Answer (score 4):

This is the recommend approach that Cypress.io suggest you use, as this is quite the anti-pattern.

[Cypress Docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Organizing-Tests-Logging-In-Controlling-State)

> Anti-Pattern: Sharing page objects, using your UI to log in, and not taking shortcuts.
>
> Best Practice: Test specs in isolation, programmatically log into your application, and take control of your application’s state.

You should have one spec file/few tests that do actually test your login screen/functionality, to confirm that is does indeed work.

But then any other time you should programmatically log into your account via an API and store the credentials in a cookie or token.

That way you should be able to bypass the login screen.

Once you have the API working you can add it into a `before` hook in the appropriate place.

Comment: this is solution for multiple tests in single file but I want login persist in multiple spec fiels

Comment: How are you storing user authentication to persist? You'll need to save/store your auth mechanism locally and then call it before each test. 

So you only do the login Auth once, but you'll need to use it multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

This is easily possible if you use the login before all tests, and after that, you have to set up cookies by default. I did this inside `cypress/support/index.ts` because it loads first.

```js
before(() => {
    cy.yourLoginHook()
})
 
Cypress.Cookies.defaults({
    preserve: 'yourCookie',
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cy.session` to create and reuse the user sessions during the login phasis.
Also, if you want to reuse sessions in any spec, you can add `cacheAcrossSpecs: true` option, in `cy.session` arguments. A user session will then be created only once.

See the documentation for more details
https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/session

Answer (score -1):

If someone else will have similar problem or Kashif is still interested I think i have solution.

You can wrap the each test (whole file also should work) inside your spec files into "export function" and use them in an other spec file that will be processed with cypress IDE.

utils.spec.ts:

```
export function loginTestName(){
  describe('Test Preparation', () => {
    it('Application login', () => {
      ...
    })
  })
}
```

test.spec.ts

```
loginTestName()
otherFunction()
describe('Other functions', () => {

  it('Add user', () => {
    ...
  })
})
```

Just be aware that when you warp test into export function, it won't be detected as a test by Cypress, so you need to remove them from "integration test localization" and reuse them in another file after moving.